# Unable to query API and use API response reference 'swell.components[].height' due to syntax error from the brackets in 'swell.components[].height'

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

Here is a link to their API documentation: http://magicseaweed.com/developer/forecast-api

I want to use the 'swell.components[].height' in a javascript function. See swell.components[].height in line 4 of my code. Getting a syntax error because of the brackets: 'Unexpected token ]':

```
function xyz(data) {
    var $media = $('#media');
    $.each(data, function(i, moreData) {
        $media.append('<table><tr><td>time: ' + moreData.localTimestamp +'</td><td>Wind: ' + moreData.wind.direction + '</td><td>Wind Speed: ' + moreData.wind.speed + '</td><td>Temperature: ' + moreData.condition.temperature + '</td><td>Wave height: ' + swell.components[].height + '</td></tr></table>');
    });
}   

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://magicseaweed.com/api/myapikey/forecast/?spot_id=1134&fields=localTimestamp,wind.speed,wind.direction,condition.temperature,swell.components[].height&callback=xyz",

        // The name of the callback parameter
        jsonp: "xyz",

        // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
        dataType: "jsonp",
    });
});
```

Comment: Why did you put `components[]` if in the docs the object is `components`?

Comment: `swell` is inside the api response json. Passed to `xyz(data)` you need to "walk" that data object. Use console.log to see what it really looks like. EDIT: missed some code, probably use the moreData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the example response you probably need to use

`moreData.swell.components[x].height`

where `x` is a string that is either `"combined"` or `"primary"` or `"secondary"` or `"tertiary"`

Without the quotes can use it like this:

`moreData.swell.components.combined.height`